# YII2 Ошибка - The "id" configuration for the Application is required

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь начать использовать YII2 (после ASP.NET MVC дается сложно). Как я понимаю ошибка в `config/web.php`, но не пойму в чем дело, `id` ведь указан:

```
<?php
return [
    'id' => 'crmapp',
    'basePath' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'),
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'somekeyhere'
        ],
        'urlManager'=>[
            'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
            'showScriptName'=>false
        ]
    ],
    'db'=> [
        require(__DIR__.'/db.php'),
    ]];
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The "id" configuration for the Application is required.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:220 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\web\index.php(10): yii\base\Application->__construct('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php on line 220
```

Вот index.php

```
<?php
require(__DIR__.'/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
$config = (__DIR__.'/../config/web.php');
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Полный путь к приложению c:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\

Вот так выглядит приложение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в индексном файле путь у `$config` правильно написан? Как, собственно и другие пути в индексном файле

Comment: Вроде yii2 по-умолчанию больше настроек в файл конфига пихает. Не пробовал вернуть обратно, что удалил?

Comment: @Razzwan, я не удалял, в примере, который я читаю, создается это все вручную.

Comment: Вы делали какие-либо перемещения файлов/папок? Пути в index.php проверили?

Comment: @Razzwan, я все папки создавал вручную, то есть это не шаблон, скачанный композером.

Comment: Расположение папок имеет логическую ошибку. Я бы на вашем месте изучал Yii2 по другому источнику. Этот оставляет сомнения в своей компетенции.

Comment: В папке web должны быть расположены только файлы, доступные из веб. Здесь нельзя хранить конфиг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расположение файлов имеет логическую ошибку. В папке web нельзя хранить конфиг. К этой папке есть доступ из сети и ваши конфиги может увидеть любобй посетитель. Их нужно хранить на уровень выше. Там же, где и папка vendor.

Для вашего случая в файле index.php так же имеем ошибку. Неправильно указаны маршруты. Должно быть так:

```
<?php
    require(__DIR__.'/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
    $config = (__DIR__.'/config/web.php');
    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Меняйте источник информации, ваш оставляет сомнения в компетенции.